# Is it possible to rename a maven jar-with-dependencies?

Tags: java, maven-2, jar, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm currently using the jar-with-dependencies assembly to create such a jar.  However, the name of my jar is a bit long.

Since this jar is being used by RPG programs on an AS400, I'd like to shorten it to make life a bit easier for those developers.  But, other than by hand, I've not found a way to rename the jar from the usual `project-name-version-classifier-jar-with-dependencies.jar`.  I'd like something like `project-name-version-classifier-full.jar`

Is there anyway to do this without basically copying the jar-with-dependencies assembly descriptor and calling it full?

Additionally, I want to continue to have the jar without the classpath assembled stored in the repository.

I need two artifacts.  The jar with my classifier holding the region which the build is for.  The jar with all dependencies which also includes the region.

`project-name-version-region-full.jar` and `project-name-version-region.jar` should be stored in the repository.  In the first example the classifier is region-full, in the 2nd it's region.  The latter is working.

Answer (score 278, accepted):

You can specify the *finalName* property to give the jar the name you want, and specify that *appendAssemblyId* should be false to avoid the "jar-with-dependencies" suffix.

The configuration below will output a jar called "test.jar"

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2-beta-4</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <finalName>test</finalName>
        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

---

Update: based on your comments, using the built-in descriptor won't work . I believe this is down to a bug in the recent versions of the assembly-plugin - they've removed support for classifiers, but the id is fixed if you use a built-in descriptor, so you end up with a big daft name.

As a workaround, you can copy the assembly descriptor used by the [jar-with-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies) descriptor and modify the id.

This example would result in the assembly id being appended to the finalName, so if you need to have a name of *region-full.jar*, you can specify the finalName as *region* and the assembly id as *full*. This will result in a file in target called region-full.jar, but note it will still be installed to the Maven repository as an attached artifact with *full* used as the classifier. As long as this id is different to that for your other assembly there should be no collision though.

The pom configuration would look like this.

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2-beta-4</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
      <phase>prepare-package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <descriptors>
          <descriptor>src/main/assembly/jar-assembly.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
        <finalName>region</finalName>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

and the jar-assembly.xml in src/main/assembly like this:

```
<assembly>
  <id>full</id>
  <formats>
    <format>jar</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <unpack>true</unpack>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</directory>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Comment: Working on that elaboration Rich.  Essentially, I need two classifier artifacts to be stored.  With appendAssemblyId turned on, I had 3 artifiacts, one without classifier, the classifier version, and the jar-with-dependencies version.  with appendAssemblyID turned off the uber jar is installed to the non-classifier version.  I need to have these guys use a region+full based classifier that says where they were built for.  Unfortunately adding the classifier tag does not work.

Comment: thanks, i use <finalName>${artifactId}-${version}-fat</finalName>, what a messy documentation

Answer (score 43):

I think I've found a way to configure this directly in the pom without needing a separate jar-assembly.xml.

It's basically the same as Rich's answer, except the finalName is specified with the artifactId and version.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-full</finalName>
        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>com.mycompany.MyMainClass</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-my-jar-with-dependenciess</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 9):

It is also possible to overwrite the original jar file by using `${project.build.finalName}` as final name:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
   <executions>
      <execution>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
             <goal>single</goal>
          </goals>
      </execution>
   </executions>
   <configuration>
     <descriptorRefs>
       <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
     </descriptorRefs>
     <finalName>${project.build.finalName}</finalName>
     <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
   </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Comment: This worked. Important lines to highlight is "<finalName>${project.build.finalName}</finalName>
<appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>"

Comment: It may be an "anti-pattern" but to answer the question here above we could use this:
`<finalName>${project.build.finalName}-full</finalName>`. At least, that worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to the posts here and some digging in the [maven docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html) I've come up with the following configuration for a general one-off repacked executable jar assembly with a custom name.

In pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>exe</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals><goal>single</goal></goals>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>MyJarName</finalName>
                <attach>false</attach>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>karlthepagain.MyMain</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

In assembly.xml:

```
<assembly>
    <id>exe</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

This will produce `MyJarName.jar` with all of its dependencies re-packaged into that same jar and the specified `Main-Class: karlthepagain.MyMain`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to give Rich the credit for pointing me in the right direction, but wanted to post the solution that worked for me as Rich's was slightly off:

My jar-assembly.xml looked like this which allowed the assembly id to change for the region which was stored as an property in my profile:

```
<assembly>
  <id>${env}-full</id>
    <formats>
      <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
      <dependencySet>
        <unpack>true</unpack>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
    <fileSets>
      <fileSet>
        <directory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</directory>
      </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

I did not use the finalName parameter in the maven-assembly-plugin settings as this built my project with my project-name-version-env-full.jar name where env-full was the classifier.

Imagine my surprise when I learned the assembly xml could be parameterized by items in the build.  This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
<build>
    <finalName>anynameyoulike</finalName>
    <plugins>           
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>                   
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.mycompany.MyMainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```