# How to rename the jar downloaded as dependency in maven

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-jar-plugin

I am trying to include a jar from the repository but I want to rename the jar when I use it.

Currently I am doing like

```
  <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>test</finalName>
                            <includes>
                                <include>original-jar-name</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

But there is no effect of the above.
I have already taken help from :
[Maven - How to rename the output classifier of a jar name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18190593/maven-how-to-rename-the-output-classifier-of-a-jar-name)

[Controlling maven final name of jar artifact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238944/controlling-maven-final-name-of-jar-artifact)

[Is it possible to rename a maven jar-with-dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334999/is-it-possible-to-rename-a-maven-jar-with-dependencies)

But that did not worked.

How is it achievable ?

Comment: What do you mean by  "when I use it"? Are you building a WAR or EAR file? Or is there a different place where you want to "use" the jar?

Comment: I am trying to use it in a spring boot jar

Comment: Then I would look for options in the spring boot maven plugins  to change the file name. WAR and EAR plugins have such options.

Comment: Why do you need to rename it? Does not make sense? in particular in a Spring Boot App ...The above configuration could have any effect cause [maven-jar-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html) does not have any kind of configuration like this. Neither `<finalName>..</finalName>` and includes is meant for parts of the current build not for dependencies...